# SQLAlchemy Hybrid Methods - using Python and/or expressions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When using SQLAlchemy's awesome hybrid methods feature, can I simply use python expressions for 'and' and 'or', or do I need to also provide the @.expression attribute to explicitly construct a SQLAlchemy query and_ / or_ construct?

e.g would this "just work" inside a Query.filter(Object.my_method(some_target_value) ?

```
class Object(db.Model):
  ...

  @hybrid_method
  def my_method(self, target):
    return not self.target or self.target == target
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly provide the expression. The reason is that the boolean operators are not overridable (because they do short-circuit evaluation), so when `self.target` is the column, `not self.target or self.target == target` just evaluates to `self.target == target`, because `self.target` is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

univerio's answer is correct, there is another pitfall specifically to my use case, so I'll post the full answer for correct usage:

```
class Object(db.Model):
  ...

  @hybrid_method
  def my_method(self, target):
    return not self.target or self.target == target

  @my_method.expression
  def my_method(cls, target):
    return or_(
      cls.target == None,  # noqa - SQLAlchemy filters must use equality rather than 'is'
      cls.target == target
    )
```